# How to map on a array and return a object with tslint. (syntactic sugar)

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

This is a pure *syntactic sugar* question.

#### How can I iterate over a array with `map` and return a new object without having TSLint saying:

> This arrow function body can be simplified by omitting the curly braces and the keyword 'return', and wrapping the object literal in parentheses.

For example, the object user:

```
class User {
    constructor(
        public id: number, 
        public first_name: string, 
        public last_name: string, 
        public gender: Date, 
        public location: number, 
    )
}
```

And when I do this :

```
const simple_users = users.map(u => { return { name: u.name, id: u.id} });
```

Then this happens :

```
[tslint] This arrow function body can be simplified by omitting the curly braces and the
keyword 'return', and wrapping the object literal in parentheses. (arrow-return-shorthand)
```

And I want to keep the tslint rule `arrow-return-shorthand`.

Comment: Have you tried omitting the curly braces and the keyword 'return', and wrapping the object literal in parentheses?

Comment: Error says it all! That's the answer to your question.

Comment: Like Amit said, Thank you :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply wrap your object inside `()`(parenthesis) and remove the `function` and `return` statement. The shorthand is below.

```
const simple_users = users.map(u => ({ name: u.name, id: u.id}));
```

Further `destructuring` version would be more shorten.

```
const simple_users = users.map(({name, id}) => ({ name, id}));
```

Comment: **So simple !** Thank you !